# Filter objects with a datetime range (00:00 to 23:59:99) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-timezone

I used django model filter with date.

Origin data has time of Africa/Abidjan(UTC+00:00) and I save this data on my database.

I set timezone about Asia/Seoul(UTC+09:00)and it's save well in my database.

But I filter data with time_range=[2015-11-15, 2015-11-16], I got data about from 15 o'clock to 14 o'clock. I want to get data from 0 o'clock to 23 o'clock.

How can I get this? I do [this url](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2759/), but it doesn't work well.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

If I have a model like post, and I get date from user.

```
input_date = '2015-11-16' (from user)
from_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
to_date = from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
posts = Post.objects.filter(created_time__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

I used upper code and got data from 2015-11-15 15:00:00 to 2015-11-16 14:00:00.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Please post minimal code needed to recreate this error. Currently it is not clear how do you pass dates into `__range` filter and what type they are.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, Thanks, I got it. I add some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can to to have a range datetime from **2015-11-16 00:00** to **2015-11-16 23:59:99**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import datetime 

input_date = '2015-11-16'
# convert string to datetime
from_date = dt.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
# combine `from_date` with min time value (00:00)
from_date = datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.min)
# combine `from_date` with max time value (23:59:99) to have end date
to_date = datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.max)
posts = Post.objects.filter(created_time__range=(from_date, to_date))
```

You can also use :

```python
from datetime import datetime

input_date = '2015-11-16'
# convert string to datetime
from_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    created_time__year=from_date.year, 
    created_time__month=from_date.month,
    created_time__day=from_date.day,
)
```

In your case, use :

```python
datetime.datetime.combine(from_date,datetime.time.max).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't know why it doesn't work. It start time 15 o'clock like pictures.

Comment: yeah, that's strange. I did some test with similar objects, and I get them between 00:00 and 23:59:99. could you add your entire function please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need data between two days. This is [code](https://gist.github.com/egaoneko/3f6e4dbc195b947b5808) using filter. If you need whole project, I change my github public.

Comment: I find a reason. It caused by native datetime. So, I edited "datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.max).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)" and It works well.